# How to present/organize repetitive data contained in cells in excel?

Tags: excel, data-cleaning, data-representation, organized

Would there be a better way to present/organize repetitive data contained in cells in excel? I've provided a set of sample data below (I can't show my actual records for confidentiality reasons) just so that you guys could visualize the data.

Country | Type  | Company   | Department    | Project   | Currency  | Amount

USA | Restaurant    | Bob's Barbeque    | Sanitation    | Monthly Sanitation | Records Database | USD   | 100

USA | Restaurant    | Bob's Barbeque    | Human Resources   | Staff Timesheet   USD | 203

USA | Restaurant    | Bob's Barbeque    | Human Resources   | Email Portal for Employees    | USD   | 259

USA | Manufacturing | Duff Autos    | Research and Development  | Inventory System|     USD | 234

USA | Manufacturing | Duff Autos    | Sales | Inventory System  | USD   | 654

China   | Manufacturing | Weihua Electronics    | Research and Development |    Inventory System    | RMB   | 102

China   | Government    | Department of Tourism |   Advertisement   | Billboard Design and Deployment Web Portal    | RMB   | 2044

As you can see, it contains a lot of repetitive data like the "Country" and the "Type". It may look organized as it is but it looks cluttered as the data multiplies. I've thought this thoroughly over the past few days but I still can't figure out a way to do organize it such that it would look pretty.

I've tried Excel's filter functionality, sorting, and others but I still think it looks cluttered. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You can just hide the column

Comment: A pivot table should remove the repeating data.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot the data, then you can open and close the sections as you please. I just did it on your sample, then in the resulting pivot tick all the fields, drag the amount one from row labels to values then click on the little down arrow and choose value field settings.

Select Sum and press OK.

the + and - on the data in the pivot allows you to fold open and close the fields to make it look however you like.